# How to convert query to Laravel Eloquent ORM

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Here is the SQL query that I want to convert to Laravel eloquent ORM.

```sql
SELECT v.product_id
  FROM (
      SELECT product_id, count(*) AS matches 
        FROM product where filter_id IN (2,4)
    GROUP BY product_id
  ) AS v
WHERE v.matches = 2
```

Here is the code I tried. it returns all the `filter_id` that contains 2 or 4. I want to get the `product_id` that has `filter_id` 2 **and** 4.

```php
$filter = [2, 4];

 $products = 
OcProductFilter::with('product')
->whereHas('product', function ($query) use ($filter) {
      $query->whereIn('oc_product_filter.filter_id', array($filter));
    })->get();
```

Here is the model of `OcProductFilter`

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class OcProductFilter extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'product_id';
    protected $table = 'oc_product_filter';
    protected $fillable = ["filter_id", 'product_id'];
    protected $hidden = [];


    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\OcProduct', 'product_id', 'product_id');
    }
}
```

Here is product_filter table 
[table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EblMk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the following raw MySQL query, which does not require any subquery:

```
SELECT product_id, COUNT(*) AS matches 
FROM product
WHERE filter_id IN (2, 4)
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING matches = 2;
```

Your updated Laravel/Eloquent code:

```
OcProductFilter::with('product')
    ->select('product_id', DB::raw('COUNT(*) matches'))
    ->groupBy('product_id')
    ->whereIn('filter_id', [2, 4])
    ->havingRaw('matches = ?', [2])
    ->get();
```